# Will an ostream flush other stream?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm curious about why I output by different ostream, and don't flush them, but when program exited, they won't mess up the order, does an ostream flush others stream?how C++ standard library make they communicate?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::clog << "flush test1 by clog\n";
    std::cout << "flush test1 by cout\n";
    std::cout << "flush test2 by cout\n";
    std::clog << "flush test2 by clog\n";
    return 0;
}

/* The output is
 * flush test1 by clog
 * flush test1 by cout
 * flush test2 by cout
 * flush test2 by clog
 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clog` stream is usually the same as the `cerr` stream, which is, depending on your library either line-buffer or not buffered meaning that at least after a line break (`\n`) it is written onto your terminal. `cout` on the other hand might be either fully buffered (only written if the buffer is full or flushed), line-buffered or not buffered. Even more specific from `cplusplus.com`: (`"If stdout is known to not refer to an interactive device, the stream is fully buffered. Otherwise, it is library-dependent whether the stream is line buffered or not buffered by default."`). Assuming your terminal is interactive, the `cout` buffer is written to your termial at least after every line.

Comment: It's strange, C++ Primer fifth edition said in default case, clog will not be bufferd, how to explain it?

Comment: The result look like both cout and clog are flush after every line break

Comment: And I am using Visual C++ compiler

Comment: Indeed both clog and cout might be flushed after every line break, but they are not guaranteed to be. Additionally both might be flushed after every character, and cout might even only be flushed manually or if its internal buffer is full. The latter only happens if the stream is explicitly marked as non interactive.

Comment: And have any example to show those stream are buffered, I want to see some way to mess up the output order? thank you

Comment: I have tested on wcout and normal cout, but the order always correct

Comment: That might be because your buffers are not buffered. On my MacBook (tested gcc and clang) as well as when using onlinegdb.com (that's probably gcc) buffers appear to be not buffered, so I assume gcc and clang both use that for cout and cerr.